# How to see full warning messages during phpunit test?

Tags: php, phpunit, vagrant, simple-phpunit

The terminal only tells me `There was 1 Warning:`. But how can I see the full warning message and where it's being triggered from?
[image: Screenshot of terminal]

---
this is my phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit
        colors="true"
        verbose="true"
        stopOnFailure="false"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="tests">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: In the question the used PHPUnit version is 7.3.0
My answer is related to PHPUnit 10.x, but I still hope this will help somebody.

<pre><code>
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
    displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"
    colors="true">
</phpunit>`
</code></pre>

Comment: Kudos to @AndorDávid! `displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"` worked for me using PHPUnit 10.

Comment: @AndorDávid That should be an answer

Answer (score 11):

Adding @AndorDávid comment as the the answer so it's easier to digest:

Use this config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PHPUnit
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"     
  displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"
  colors="true">
  <!-- rest of the config file -->
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it is worthy to mention another approach how to show "warnings" that came from PHP during PHPUnit testing.

**One way** is to show all PHP Errors by enabling PHP error reporing using `error_reporting(E_ALL)`  `setUp()` method in your tests:

```
public function setUp(): void
{
  # Turn on error reporting
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  // ...
}
```

Hereafter compare verbosity of either solutions:

**First example of output with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`:**

```
PHPUnit 11.0.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.2.0
Configuration: C:\...\tests\phpunit.xml

.
Warning: Undefined property: stdClass::$idc in C:\...\lib\MyClass.php on line 324
W                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 00:01.221, Memory: 26.00 MB
```

**Second way** was already mentioned in other answers is using `displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"` attribute in `phpunit.xml` config file.

**Second example of output with `displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"` :**

```
PHPUnit 11.0.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.2.0
Configuration: C:\...\tests\phpunit.xml

.W                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 00:01.204, Memory: 26.00 MB

1 test triggered 1 PHP warning:

1) C:\Users\...\lib\MyClass.php:324
Undefined property: stdClass::$foo

Triggered by:

* MyClassTest::test_MyClass_searchById
  C:\Users\...\tests\MyClassTest.php:414

OK, but there were issues!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 4, Warnings: 1.
```